# Are these dream posters from Inside Out parodies of real films?

Tags: reference, posters, inside-out

During Inside Out, Joy, Sadness and Bing Bong visit Dream Productions. There are several posters on the walls for "movies" that are broadcast into Riley's dreams.

I found a list of them [here](http://www.fanpop.com/clubs/inside-out/picks/show/1513636/which-movie-released-dream-production-most-captivating-watch) which I've put together:

[image: Inside Out posters]

They are:

- I'm Falling For A Very Long Time Into A Pit
- I Can Fly!
- Something's Chasing Me!
- I Woke Up And Was A Princess
- Riley Andersen Can Breath [sic] Underwater
- Where Are My Pants?!

I instantly recognised the first one as a parody of the Vertigo film poster, however I cannot place the rest. I've done some research and several places (e.g. [Pixar Wikia](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Dream_Productions)) mention they are parodies but give only Vertigo as an example:

> Many of the posters are direct parodies of real life film posters. The poster for "I'm Falling for a Very Long Time Into a Pit" is very similar to the poster for Alfred Hitchcock's 1958 thriller, Vertigo.

Are the other posters references to specific films?

Comment: They look pretty generic. It might be that the only evidence those "several places" are grabbing onto is really just the *Vertigo* poster (which isn't that non-generic itself either). But interesting question (even if we might want to keep it under surveillance and police it for single-item speculation answers a little).

Comment: I somehow missed it before but I think "Someone's Chasing Me" is a parody of [this Psycho poster](http://www.iceposter.com/thumbs/MOV_67d2d647_b.jpg).

Comment: Ah, good catch. The last one looks suspiciously familiar, too.

Comment: Last one is probably *"Dude, Where's My Car"*

Comment: The Castle looks a lot like these ones: https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/6/37/uRAsxb.jpg and https://i0.wp.com/chipandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/sleepingbeauty-e1548346963124-600x410.png?resize=600%2C410&ssl=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, the top left poster appears to be a parody of Vertigo. As for the others, here are my best guesses, based on the image shape and style, and the text which appear to be both common nightmare or dream themes, and oblique references to the movies they parody, plus suggestions from the comments:

1. Top Left: [Vertigo](http://www.allposters.com/-sp/Vertigo-Posters_i3406496_.htm)
2. Top Middle: [Peter Pan](http://www.moviepostershop.com/peter-pan-movie-poster-1953/EB42604)
3. Top Right: [Psycho](http://www.iceposter.com/posters/movies/Psycho_movie_posters_(1960)/MOV_67d2d647_Psycho_movie_poster_(1960)_Poster.html#.WLTW8tKP9EY) (suggested by DisgruntledGoat in the comments).
4. Bottom Left: [Disney's Sleeping beauty](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/File:Sleeping_Beauty_1990's_Re-Release_Poster.jpg)
5. Bottom Middle: [Finding Nemo / Finding Dory](http://henryaquino.com/can-you-find-dory-in-disney-pixars-latest-animated-poster/)
6. Bottom Right: [Dude, where's my car](http://www.impawards.com/2000/dude_wheres_my_car.html) (Suggested by Paulie_D in the comments)

Comment: Can you provide some actual visual cues to substantiate your guesses a little more? Are there specific posters you can reference here or is this just based on the fact that Peter Pan can fly too (what version of Peter Pan do you even mean)? *If* you think the references are less based around the specific posters and more generally about existing movies, you might want to point that out, too. Please tell us *why* you think this is a reasonable answer, since as it stands it reads more more like idle speculation.

Comment: Most of the posters you link to don't really present much of a similarity. And the story connections seem rather superficial.

Answer (score 1):

For the last one, also, the title is probably a parody of that scene from The Lego Movie.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or clip showing exactly what you’re referring to?